# Upper bound for the crossed-terms of a sum of multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, multinomial-coefficients

I am trying to upper bound the variance of a centered tree and I would like to get an upper bound which would look like : $$\sum\limits_{\substack{ (l_1, ..., l_d) \neq (k_1, ..., k_d), \\ \sum_{j=1}^d l_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^d k_{j} = k } } \frac{k!}{k_{1}! ... k_{d} !} \frac{k!}{l_{1}!... l_{d} !} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{\sum_{j=1}^d \mathbb{1}_{l_j \neq k_j}} \leq  C_d d^{2k} \varepsilon(k)$$
where $C_d$ is any constant depending only on $d$ and $\varepsilon(k)$ tends to $0$ as $k$ tends to infinity. We are summing over both $l_j$s and $k_j$s. We know that a single sum of multinomial coefficients equals $d^k$. Therefore, writing $k =qd+r$, I tried to distinguish two parts of the sum, a part $A$ where $\left(1/2\right)^{\sum_{j=1}^d \mathbb{1}_{l_j \neq k_j}} \leq (1/2)^q$ and we have $$A \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^q d^{2k}, $$ and another part $B$ which contains much less terms (only the terms where $\sum_{j=1}^d \mathbb{1}_{l_j \neq k_j} \leq q-1$) with something polynomial in $k$ (i.e $k^d+...$) but I've been unsuccessful so far.

The overall sum comes from, with $x \in [0,1]^d$ a given point and $X$ a uniform random variable on $[0,1]^d$, $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \sum\limits_{\substack{(k_1, ..., k_d), \\ \sum_{j=1}^d k_{j} = k } } \frac{k!}{k_{1}! ... k_{d} !} \left(\frac{1}{d}\right)^k \prod_{j=1}^d \mathbb{1}_{\lceil 2^{k_j} x_j\rceil = \lceil 2^{k_j} X_j\rceil} \right)^2\right] $$
where $\lceil y \rceil$ corresponds to the first integer $m$ such that $m \geq y$.

I welcome any suggestions or ideas and would be happy to discuss this problem with you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you cannot hope for $\epsilon(k)$ going to zero. Using the identity
$$(x_1+\ldots+x_d)^k=\sum_{0\leq k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_d\leq k_1+\ldots+k_d=k}\frac{k!x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_d^{k_d}}{k_1!\cdots k_d!}$$
we get the lower bound
$$2^{-d}d^{2k}-\sum_{0\leq k_1,\ldots,k_d\leq k_1+\ldots+k_d=d}\left(\frac{k!}{k_1!\cdots k_d!}\right)^2$$ (take the square of the above identity and set $x_1=\ldots=x_d=1$) on your quantity.

We have yet to show that the
correction
$$C=\sum_{0\leq k_1,\ldots,k_d\leq k_1+\ldots+k_d=d}\left(\frac{k!}{k_1!\cdots k_d!}\right)^2$$
is $o(d^{2k})$.

Since contributions to
$$A=\sum_{0\leq k_1,\ldots,k_d\leq k_1+\ldots+k_d=d}\frac{k!}{k_1!\cdots k_d!}$$
behave roughly like a multiple of a Gaussian centered at $\frac{1}{d}(k,k,\ldots,k)$ with variance of order $\sqrt{k}$, the size of $C$ is roughly (up to a constant asymptotically) given by
$$\frac{A^2}{\sqrt{k}^d}=d^{2k}\sqrt{k}^{-d}$$ which ends the proof.

Comment: Thank you really much for your fast answer !

Comment: Your insights on how to interpret A are very useful. I indeed read that $C=o(d^{2k})$ and I understand why the lower bound is not a $o(d^{2k})$.

Comment: The Gaussian picture is useful for asymptotics since one can almost  think of a Gaussian distribution as a (normalized) characteristic function whose support is described in terms of its variance.